# Will I get desktop Ubuntu after connecting Samsung Galaxy Nexus to TV via HDMI?

Tags: installation, display, phone

I have a Galaxy Nexus phone, I´d like to know, if I get a full desktop Ubuntu after I connect it with a TV via HDMI. I can´t find the answer. If it´s true, there´s no need for me to have a laptop :-)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you get the same video output via HDMI as you have on the phone's screen. It's nice for watching movies but this is the only useful use case right now. Hopefully the docking mode will be implemented soon.